# Getting exception creating new poolable object on running Oracle OAF page

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, jdeveloper, oaf

I am creating an Oracle OAF application on JDeveloper. Everything seems to be working fine - no compilation errors, the database connection is working but when I run my page, I am getting exception: oracle.apps.fnd.common.AppsException: oracle.apps.fnd.common.PoolException: Exception creating new Poolable object. The stack trace is pretty long and it ends like this: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException.

This issue came out of nowhere, earlier the page was running fine. Nothing seems to solve this. Any ideas how to resolve this?

I tried basic configuration checks - DBC file, environment variable, reinstalling Oracle Jdeveloper, tried the same approach on multiple projects but the issue was the same every time. I was expecting the page to finally run but I kept getting the exception as said earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The APPL_SERVER_ID in the DBC file had changed and I was tried to run the page with the old one.